# Vector3 Scale matrix in OpenGL and OpenTK, C#

Tags: c#, opengl, vector, scale, opentk

I want to apply transforms to my OpenGL project, using C#. To apply the position, I just did:

```
modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(position);
```

With "position" being a Vector3.

To the rotation, I did:

```
public void UpdateRotation()
        {
            gameObject.mesh.modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rotation.x);
            gameObject.mesh.modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rotation.y);
            gameObject.mesh.modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rotation.z);
        }
```

With "rotation" also being a Vector3.

But, now, I need to apply the scale, but OpenTK's Matrix4 only have the "Matrix4.CreateScale()" method, that takes a **float** "scale" as input, and not a **Vector3**.

How can I fix this problem and scale using a Vector3, instead of float.

Comment: The rotation code does not work, it only rotates around the z axis.
Also, the [documentation](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Mathematics.Matrix4.html#OpenTK_Mathematics_Matrix4_CreateScale_OpenTK_Mathematics_Vector3_) clearly shows a method with scale being a vector3

Comment: Hello! 
First of all, yes, the rotation code it not working, but I didn't want to put that here, because it would be another question.
Second, I found that article you posted, but I was trying to use another Vector3 class, and not "OpenTK.Mathmatics.Vector3". That was the problem.